# Как удалить из текста определенные ссылки?

Tags: php

Есть строка, например:

`Lorem Ipsum is simply <a href="example.html">dummy</a> text of the printing and typesetting <a href="#test">industry</a>. Lorem Ipsum has been...`

Как из нее удалить все ссылки (включая текст ссылки *на примере это industry*), атрибут `href` которой начинается с **#** ?

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Приведите ожидаемый результат.

Comment: @СвободуСергеюСуровцеву `Lorem Ipsum is simply <a href="example.html">dummy</a> text of the printing and typesetting. Lorem Ipsum has been...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать `DomDocument`

```
$string = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply <a href="example.html">dummy</a> text of the printing and typesetting <a href="#test">industry</a>. Lorem Ipsum has been...';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($string, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);
$domElem = $dom->documentElement;

$tags = $domElem->getElementsByTagName('a');

foreach ($tags as $key => $tag) {
    if(strpos($tag->getAttribute("href"), '#') !== false){
        $tag->parentNode->removeChild($tag);
    }
}

$result = $dom->saveHTML($domElem);
print_r($result);
```